# Scrolling floating objects but if outside page width don't show them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two fixed position arrows for next and previous blog posts on my blog. http://www.top5best4you.com

Though if the browser window size is too small it will still show them and they will be over the top of te content on the page.

Is there a way for me to hide them if the browser size is stoo small to display them properly?

Cheers.

Comment: Not seeing the arrows... Where on the page are they?

Comment: Click on any of the single posts please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use media queries.

Put this code in your `<head>`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`

Then, set your arrows to `display: none;` in your CSS, and add this at the bottom of your CSS file:

`@media all and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .prevpost, .nextpost { display: block; }
}`

Comment: looking into this. Is that what the min width needs to be? Thanks

Comment: Approximately, yes. Much narrower than that and the arrows start to overlap the main content.